# Complex power property

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove:
$(zw)^{a} = z^{a}w^{a}$ with all the elements in $\mathbb{C}$

By definition:
$$(zw)^{a} = e^{a \log(zw)}$$
Propery of $\log$:
$$(zw)^{a} = e^{a [\log(z) + \log(w)]}$$

Addition propoerty of exponential power:
$$(zw)^{a} = e^{a\log(z)}e^{a\log(w)}$$
By property X:
$$(zw)^{a} = [e^{\log(z)}]^{a}[e^{\log(w)}]^{a}$$
$\log$ is an iverse function of $e^{z}$:
$$(zw)^{a} = z^{a}w^{a}$$

My problem is property X. I do not have any idea how to prove it ¿Any hint?

Comment: You can skip property X and just use the definition (as in your first step) to deduce $e^{a\log(z)}=z^a$

Comment: note that logarithms and powers may not be uniquely defined for complex numbers

Answer (score 2):

First, if we wish to consider $$(z_1 z_2)^a$$ then note that if $z_1 = z_2 = -1$ and $a = i$ then we have
$$ (z_1 z_2)^w = 1^i = 1$$

but

\begin{align}
z_1^a z_2^a &= (-1)^i \cdot (-1)^i \\
&= e^{-\pi} \cdot e^{-\pi} \\
&= e^{-2\pi}.
\end{align}

Thus,

$$(z_1 z_2)^a \neq z_1^a z_2^a$$

In order for $(z_1 z_2)^a = z_1^a z_2^a$ we must have $- \pi < \arg z_1 + \arg z_2 \leq \pi$ since

\begin{align}
(z_1 z_2)^a &= e^{a \operatorname{Log} (z_1 z_2)}\\
&= z_1^a z_2^a \cdot e^{2n \pi i},
\end{align}

and $n = 0$ only when $- \pi < \arg z_1 + \arg z_2 \leq \pi$.